# How to do: underline, bold, italic, strikethrough, color, background, and size in Gnome Terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, scripts

How to do: underline, bold, italic, strikethrough, and color in Gnome Terminal?

**Bold**

*Italic*

u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲

s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶s̶ ̶h̶o̶t

[Color](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528928/how-to-do-underline-bold-italic-strikethrough-and-color-in-gnome-terminal)

`background`

`font` < (its mono if you couldn't tell)

## size

Comment: And what exactly want to change? The prompt, the text you enter, the output of your commands?

Comment: export PS1 actually. Although I'd like it for basic echo as well.

Comment: If it supported "Faint", I'd switch.  :(

Comment: You can use `echo -e`

Answer (score 129, accepted):

> The ANSI/VT100 terminals and terminal emulators are not just able to
>   display black and white text; they can display colors and formatted
>   texts thanks to escape sequences. Those sequences are composed of the
>   Escape character (often represented by "^[" or "Esc") followed by
>   some other characters: "Esc[FormatCodem".

In Bash, the  character can be obtained with the following syntaxes:

```
\e
\033
\x1B
```

[image]

The commands (for easy copy-paste):

```
echo -e "\e[1mbold\e[0m"
echo -e "\e[3mitalic\e[0m"
echo -e "\e[3m\e[1mbold italic\e[0m"
echo -e "\e[4munderline\e[0m"
echo -e "\e[9mstrikethrough\e[0m"
echo -e "\e[31mHello World\e[0m"
echo -e "\x1B[31mHello World\e[0m"
```

Source (including all types of foreground/background color codes): http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Comment: I added three more for size, font, and background. Are these possible?

Comment: @Akiva You can easily change the background color (See the dedicated [section](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting#background)). Regarding size, I don't think it's possible. For font, the only setting is a global gconf value (`/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/font`)

Comment: @Akiva: I'd like to know what's missing^

Comment: Oh I didnt realize that I did this. I think I must have accepted it, then had an old page where it showed it was not accepted, and accepted it again :P

Comment: What about overline, is it possible?

Comment: @dashesy: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code, 53 should do the overline. But in my terminal is does nothing.

Comment: Is the trailing `m` just used as a delimiter? I could not find any documentation discussing it.

Comment: @sherrellbc a delimiter indeed (The "m" terminates each term of the escape sequence, according to http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/colorizing.html)

Comment: None of the `\e` codes work for me - only the colors (`\x`). I'm using GNU bash, version 3.2.57

Comment: @dashesy `konsole` is the only terminal emulator I'm aware of that supports overline (SGR 53). What would you use this for? I'm considering implementing it in gnome-terminal, technically it's a piece of cake, but I wouldn't want to add features that no one would use.

Comment: @egmont I remember I wanted to use it in `PS1` (in gnome-terminal actually) because underline kind of blended in the text below it making it harder to read, and of course strike-through looked just wrong. Having a line there would help spotting the previous commands when scrolling up (so does color).

Comment: @dashesy Thanks, it's actually a pretty cool use case :) Gnome-terminal progress is tracked [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=767115).

Comment: All work but italic for some reason. `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release`

Comment: Never mind, I think my problems stem from using the Gnome/MATE terminal.

Comment: @KenSharp GNOME Terminal has supported italic text for like 5 years now; recent (GTK3-based) versions of MATE Terminal also do.

Comment: Hmmmm. I don't know then. I'll have to look into it more.

Comment: On my macOS High Sierra, ```echo -e``` does Not work but using ```printf``` Does work.

Comment: `\e[0m` clears everything, including colors that have been set and other font types that may want to be retained, so are there escape codes for undoing specific font types?

Answer (score 46):

GNOME Terminal 3.28 (VTE 0.52), debuting in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, adds support for a few more styles including curly and colored underlines as seen in Kitty, overline as seen in Konsole, and finally everyone's much loved or much hated blink attribute as well.

GNOME Terminal 3.52 (VTE 0.76), debuting in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, extends the list with dotted and dashed underline.

These also automatically work in any other VTE-based terminal emulator (e.g. Tilix, Terminator, Xfce4 Terminal, Guake etc.), given that VTE is at least at the said version.

Here's a list demonstrating the standard escape sequences, as well as GNOME Terminal's (VTE's) additions. Note that for every opening sequence I'm also showing the closing sequence of that property only, rather than the generic `\e[m` or `\e[0m` that disables all special modes.

```
echo -e '\e[1mbold\e[22m'
echo -e '\e[2mdim\e[22m'
echo -e '\e[3mitalic\e[23m'
echo -e '\e[4munderline\e[24m'
echo -e '\e[4:1mthis is also underline (since 0.52)\e[4:0m'
echo -e '\e[21mdouble underline (since 0.52)\e[24m'
echo -e '\e[4:2mthis is also double underline (since 0.52)\e[4:0m'
echo -e '\e[4:3mcurly underline (since 0.52)\e[4:0m'
echo -e '\e[4:4mdotted underline (since 0.76)\e[4:0m'
echo -e '\e[4:5mdashed underline (since 0.76)\e[4:0m'
echo -e '\e[5mblink (since 0.52)\e[25m'
echo -e '\e[7mreverse\e[27m'
echo -e '\e[8minvisible\e[28m <- invisible (but copy-pasteable)'
echo -e '\e[9mstrikethrough\e[29m'
echo -e '\e[53moverline (since 0.52)\e[55m'

echo -e '\e[31mred\e[39m'
echo -e '\e[91mbright red\e[39m'
echo -e '\e[38:5:42m256-color, de jure standard (ITU-T T.416)\e[39m'
echo -e '\e[38;5;42m256-color, de facto standard (commonly used)\e[39m'
echo -e '\e[38:2::240:143:104mtruecolor, de jure standard (ITU-T T.416) (since 0.52)\e[39m'
echo -e '\e[38:2:240:143:104mtruecolor, rarely used incorrect format (might be removed at some point)\e[39m'
echo -e '\e[38;2;240;143;104mtruecolor, de facto standard (commonly used)\e[39m'

echo -e '\e[46mcyan background\e[49m'
echo -e '\e[106mbright cyan background\e[49m'
echo -e '\e[48:5:42m256-color background, de jure standard (ITU-T T.416)\e[49m'
echo -e '\e[48;5;42m256-color background, de facto standard (commonly used)\e[49m'
echo -e '\e[48:2::240:143:104mtruecolor background, de jure standard (ITU-T T.416) (since 0.52)\e[49m'
echo -e '\e[48:2:240:143:104mtruecolor background, rarely used incorrect format (might be removed at some point)\e[49m'
echo -e '\e[48;2;240;143;104mtruecolor background, de facto standard (commonly used)\e[49m'

echo -e '\e[21m\e[58:5:42m256-color underline (since 0.52)\e[59m\e[24m'
echo -e '\e[21m\e[58;5;42m256-color underline (since 0.52)\e[59m\e[24m'
echo -e '\e[4:3m\e[58:2::240:143:104mtruecolor underline (since 0.52) (*)\e[59m\e[4:0m'
echo -e '\e[4:3m\e[58:2:240:143:104mtruecolor underline (since 0.52) (might be removed at some point) (*)\e[59m\e[4:0m'
echo -e '\e[4:3m\e[58;2;240;143;104mtruecolor underline (since 0.52) (*)\e[59m\e[4:0m'
```

(*) Truecolor values for underlines are slightly approximated.

And a bit odd one that doesn't quite fit in this picture, as it's more of a functionality than a style, yet is probably worth mentioning here, is [hyperlink](https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda) support co-designed with iTerm2, available since GNOME Terminal 3.26 (VTE 0.50):

```
echo -e '\e]8;;http://askubuntu.com\e\\hyperlink (since 0.50)\e]8;;\e\\'
```

Here's a screenshot demonstrating the result:
[image: Rendering in GNOME Terminal 3.52]

Comment: A screenshot of the result would be lovely, for those of us who don't have these gnome-terminal/vte versions.

Comment: @MariusGedminas Done.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks for taking the time to collect all these! I wonder if they also work on iTerm2 (will try to check that for myself shortly...)

Answer (score 43):

To extend Sylvain's answer, some helper functions:

```
ansi()          { echo -e "\e[${1}m${*:2}\e[0m"; }
bold()          { ansi 1 "$@"; }
italic()        { ansi 3 "$@"; }
underline()     { ansi 4 "$@"; }
strikethrough() { ansi 9 "$@"; }
red()           { ansi 31 "$@"; }
```

Then

[image]

Comment: echo "$(bold "this doesn't $(italic really) work for all purposes though")"

Answer (score 29):

Something that has not been covered yet is the **combination** of two or three parameters, e. g. *bold* and *underline*, in a predefined color. This is achieved by a 3-way syntax, for instance:

```
~$ printf "\e[3;4;33mthis is a test\n\e[0m"
```

will cause "this is a test" to be printed in yellow color (**`33m`**), italic (**`3m`**) AND underlined (**`4m`**).
Note that it is *not* necessary to repeat the `\e[` every time.
Note too that (alike to Sylvain) I also added a `\e[0m` to reset settings every time, because otherwise the yellow color and the font style will remain active in terminal! Needless to say that you absolutely have to watch out for these to get reset in scripts, because users who use your scripts may dislike it if your script *permanently* modifies their color + style settings in terminal!

Answer (score 16):

*Replace these hard-coded sequences by:*

```
tput smul # set underline
tput rmul # remove underline

tput smso # set bold on
tput rmso # remove bold

tput setaf 1 #red
tput setaf 2 #green
...
tput cup 0 0 # move to pos 0,0
```

Refer to "man terminfo" and "man tput" for complete descriptions of these commands.

*Example :*

```bsh
function f_help
{
  c_green=$(tput  setaf 2      2>/dev/null)
  c_reset=$(tput  sgr0         2>/dev/null)
  c_bold=$(tput smso           2>/dev/null)
  echo "${c_bold}DESCRIPTION${c_reset} : .... ${c_green}My green text${c_reset}My plain text"
}
```

Comment: Doing it in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199285/tput-cup-in-python-on-the-commandline

Comment: Note that `smso` sets `standout` not `bold`. `standout` is usually the combination of reverse and bold. There is no standard tput/terminfo/termcap capability for turning off `bold`, however [ECMA-48:1991](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf) defines SGR 22 as "normal colour or normal intensity (neither bold nor faint)" so you can reasonably use `echo -ne "\\033[22m"` in `bash`.