# Displaying unicode strikethrough in gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, unicode

I am trying to output strikethrough text in `gnome-terminal`. For example to output the letter `I` with strikethrough:

```
echo -e 'I\U0336'
```

But this does not work, it gives me an `I` followed by a horizonal line.
It works fine in `xterm`.

Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem related to certain fonts. See

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ttf-liberation/+bug/299158

Changing to `Ubuntu Mono` font in gnome-terminal solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need a sequences of Escape characters:

```
echo -e "\e[9mI\e[0m"
```

or using `printf`

```
printf "\e[9m%s\e[0m\n" "I"
```

---

Try this:

```
echo -e "\e[9m"
```

Then type some text and reset with:

```
echo -e "\e[0m"
```

<sub>[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/528938/367165)</sub>

Comment: Yes this works, but wonder why does it work in `xterm` without ANSI escape sequence? And why does it work in gnome-terminal if I put a trailing character after like `echo -e 'I\U0336I'` ?